# Перенос блока из flex-контейнера в адаптиве

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: aside__wrapper (display: flex, flex-direction: row); inner__wrapper (display: flex; flex-direction: column)]

Задачей является перенос блока номер 2 из контейнера aside__wrapper в адаптиве.
Проблема в самом наличии двух контейнеров разных селекторов с блоками внутри, и order не хочет работать с блоками в разных флексовых контейнерах. Может у кого есть соображения как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Без JS невозможно, если не костылить с дублированными скрытыми контейнерами

Comment: а нельзя поместить в aside_wrapper блоки 1, 3, 4 (вертикально) и в inner_wrapper 2? Блоки  aside_wrapper и  inner_wrapper расположить горизонтально

Answer (score 0):

1. Order и не должен работать с блоками в разных контейнерах.
2. По названию класса aside__wrapper можно предположить, что речь идет о сайдбаре. Вопрос: что он забыл в месте, предназначенном для основного контента?
3. Если изменить структуру контейнеров на нормальную категорически нельзя, можно спозиционировать блок № 2 абсолютно и загнать в низ экрана, но придется явно колхозить габариты.
4. Если можно поменять структуру, то следует сделать так:

   ```
   ___________________   ___________________
   |  inner__wrapper  | |   aside__wrapper  |
   |  _____           | |  _____            |
   | |  1  |          | | |  2  |           |
   | |_____|          | | |_____|           |
   |  _____           | |___________________|
   | |  3  |          | 
   | |_____|          | 
   |  _____           | 
   | |  4  |          | 
   | |_____|          | 
   |__________________|
   ```

И в мобильном виде переносить весь .aside__wrapper вниз.